Cannot Generate any Schematics using Angular CLI generate command
I'm having this problem wherein I'm getting an  Option "_name" is not defined. error when running any generate commands ng g <any_schematic>.
I tried doing npm install, using the --project argument but still getting the same results.
I'm using these versions:


I got it.
For this specific problem. Reinstall angular cli globally using
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli ( use sudo if necessary ) then, do npm cache clean --force
then reinstall angular cli globally again.

Hence, doing a fix for this specific error message requires the usual clean install of the angular-cli itself.
